# FullCalendar firstDay doesn't work

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using this code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      firstDay: 2,
      eventSources: [
        {
          url: 'data.php',
          type: 'POST'
        }
      ]
    })
  });
</script>
```

but the calendar still starts on Sunday

According to their docs, I am using it right

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably an issue with your libraries. Be sure to use the latest version of fullcalendar (2.1.1) and include momentjs.

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Check this working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/xp97rr4L/1/)