# jQuery Full Calendar firstDay changes labels but not dates

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I've seen a couple of posts here regarding this issue but with no solutions, so I'm hoping someone can help me here.

I'm working on a website that implements jQuery FullCalendar but using Year view as default. The client wants the calendar blocks to begin with Monday and not Sunday as default. Using the `firstDay` setting, I change it to 1 (Monday) and although the labels on the top change, the actual dates remain the in the same order so essentially, they are reflecting the wrong dates.

Here is my javascript code that renders the calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  theme: true,
  header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'year,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  defaultDate: '2016-01-01',
  defaultView: 'year',
  yearColumns: 3,
  firstDay: 1,
  editable: true,
  windowResize: function(view) {
      if ($(window).width() < 767){
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'month' );
      } else {
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'year' );
      }
  },
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  events: {
      url: '/wp-content/themes/morb/js/fullcalendar/demos/php/get-events.php',
      error: function() {
          $('#script-warning').show();
      }
  },
  loading: function(bool) {
      $('#loading').toggle(bool);
  }
});
```

Using the standard 0 setting, here's a shot of this month's calendar:

[image]

Implementing 1 as the first day, it now looks like this:

[image]

As you see the dates remain in the same position.

Can anyone help me out with this, and explain why this might be happening?

EDIT: As requested, my events json:

```
[{"title":"Unavailable","color":"#FF0000","start":"2016-12-30T00:00:00","end":"2017-01-02T00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/weddingtestsite.co.uk\/booking\/31st-dec-2016\/","post_id":484},{"title":"Unavailable","color":"#FF0000","start":"2016-12-23T00:00:00","end":"2016-12-26T00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/weddingtestsite.co.uk\/booking\/24th-dec-2016\/","post_id":482},{"title":"Unavailable","color":"#FF0000","start":"2016-12-16T00:00:00","end":"2016-12-19T00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/weddingtestsite.co.uk\/booking\/17th-dec\/","post_id":481},{"title":"Unavailable","color":"#FF0000","start":"2016-12-02T00:00:00","end":"2016-12-05T00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/weddingtestsite.co.uk\/booking\/3rd-dec-2016\/","post_id":480},{"title":"Unavailable","color":"#FF0000","start":"2016-12-09T00:00:00","end":"2016-12-12T00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/weddingtestsite.co.uk\/booking\/3-dec-2016\/","post_id":479},{"title":"Booked","color":"darkgreen","start":"2016-09-23T00:00:00","end":"2016-09-26T00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/weddingtestsite.co.uk\/booking\/24th-september\/","post_id":437},{"title":"Booked","color":"darkgreen","start":"2016-09-16T00:00:00","end":"2016-09-19T00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/weddingtestsite.co.uk\/booking\/17th-september-2016\/","post_id":436},{"title":"Booked","color":"darkgreen","start":"2016-10-28T00:00:00","end":"2016-10-31T00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/weddingtestsite.co.uk\/booking\/435\/","post_id":435},{"title":"Booked","color":"darkgreen","start":"2016-11-11T00:00:00","end":"2016-11-14T00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/weddingtestsite.co.uk\/booking\/432\/","post_id":432},{"title":"Booked","color":"darkgreen","start":"2016-10-21T00:00:00","end":"2016-10-24T00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/weddingtestsite.co.uk\/booking\/430\/","post_id":430},{"title":"Booked","color":"darkgreen","start":"2016-09-30T00:00:00","end":"2016-10-03T00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/weddingtestsite.co.uk\/booking\/429\/","post_id":429},{"title":"Booked","color":"darkgreen","start":"2016-09-02T00:00:00","end":"2016-09-05T00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/weddingtestsite.co.uk\/booking\/428\/","post_id":428},{"title":"Booked","color":"darkgreen","start":"2016-09-09T00:00:00","end":"2016-09-12T00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/weddingtestsite.co.uk\/booking\/427\/","post_id":427}]
```

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. Can you provide a fiddle with the error? What version of Fullcalendar and jQuery are you using?

Comment: Can you post your events JSON?

Comment: Have edited the question with the JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FullCalendar firstDay doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526280/fullcalendar-firstday-doesnt-work)